# jquery code doesn't work when contents from another page loads in specific div, without a page reload

Tags: jquery

I'm having problems getting my jquery codes to work fine on my site. I'm using php and i have previously completed the site before, but i decided to re-do it in OOP, use mysqli instead and also to make it more refined because of the site's complexity.

My OOP version is designed this way, i have a fixed header(the header contains all my jquery links) and footer, but when any nav link is clicked there is no page reload, but the content of another page is loaded into a specific div(#load_here). This is working fine, the issue i have is that when a form on another page, that submits through jquery to my database is loaded into my div(#load_here), the jquery code for that particular form doesn't work. I've tried including my jquery links to the page whose content is being loaded, but this causes my site not to work properly anymore. Any solution?

Heres some illustrative code:

```
    <html>
    <header>
            <script src="jquery-1.11.1-jquery.min.js"></script>

<scrirpt>    
    $("#nav_page_a").on("click", function () {
    $("#load_here").load("link 1.php");
    });
    $("#nav_page_b").on("click", function () {
    $("#load_here").load("link 2.php");
    });
    $("#nav_page_c").on("click", function () {
    $("#load_here").load("link 3.php");
    });
</script>

    </header>

    <body>
    <a  id="#nav_page_a" href="#">link 1</a>
    <a  id="#nav_page_b" href="#">link 2</a>
    <a  id="#nav_page_c" href="#">link 3</a>

    <div id="load_here">
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

The other page being loaded:

```
<?php
require_once 'include/initialize.php'; //Where my OOP classes are

$pages = new pages(); // a class

$pages->Link_1(); // the form html and php content
$pages->Link_1Script(); // the jquery script

?>
```

even if i decide not to separate the script jquery codes from the form contents it doesn't still work.

This is my jquery code for submitting my form:

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit_product").click(function() {
var category_key = $("#category_key").val();
var branch_code = $("#branch_code").val();
var product_name = $("#product_name").val();
var pieces = $("#pieces").val();
var measurement = $("#measurement").val();
var price = $("#price").val();
var reorder = $("#reorder").val();
var exp_date = $("#exp_date").val();
var note = $("#note").val();
if (exp_date == '' || reorder == '' || category_key == '' || pieces == '' || price == '' || branch_code == '' || measurement == '' || product_name == '') {
window.alert("Insertion Failed, Some Fields are Blank....!!");
} else {
if(pieces < reorder){
window.alert("Re-order Level cannot be greater than pieces available!!");
}else{
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("scripts/products.php", {
category_key1: category_key,
branch_code1: branch_code,
product_name1: product_name,
pieces1: pieces,
measurement1: measurement,
price1: price,
reorder1: reorder,
exp_date1: exp_date,
note1: note
}, function(data) {
window.alert("Product successfully created!!!");
$('#register_formProduct')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
});
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think its because your data is loaded later ie after the page load, that is why the events are not registered with the DOM. You have to bind the events again after the content is loaded.

Comment: i figured also, but i'm new to jquery i don't know how to do that

Comment: what does this load `$pages->Link_1Script();`?

Comment: the html and php contents only, it's from the page that is being loade

Comment: There are two ways to fix this. 1. Load all the jquery code outside. bind the events on `.load` function call back. 2. Put the jquery in each page respectively under `<script>` tag. So when html is loaded, jquery code will be executed. PS : Please load all jquery library files in parent page only.

Comment: thanks, but i'm not sure if i'll do solution 1 correctly since i'm quite new to jquery and i think i've tried 2, but it causes my site some problems. Could you help me with solution 1.

Comment: Please tell me what you want jquery to do with the new content loaded? Is it a form or something, which you want to check on submit?

Comment: it's a form that submits with jquery, i'll include the code

Comment: i have just included my jquery code

Comment: I have answered. Feel free to ask if any doubts. I think you can use a plugin for validating your form. Can help you clean up your code.

Comment: thank you very much Mr Harry. I was able to come up with it, wiht just a alittle adjust ment and all.

Comment: Thats great, glad could help. Please accept the answer for future visitors. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this should work. Put this in your parent page. I ve modified your script a bit

```
$("#nav_page_a").on("click", function () {
    $("#load_here").load("link 1.php", function(){
        $("#submit_product").on("click", function() {
            var category_key = $("#category_key").val(),
                branch_code = $("#branch_code").val(),
                product_name = $("#product_name").val(),
                pieces = $("#pieces").val(),
                measurement = $("#measurement").val(),
                price = $("#price").val(),
                reorder = $("#reorder").val(),
                exp_date = $("#exp_date").val(),
                note = $("#note").val();
            if (exp_date == '' || reorder == '' || category_key == '' || pieces == '' || price == '' || branch_code == '' || measurement == '' || product_name == '') {
                window.alert("Insertion Failed, Some Fields are Blank....!!");
                return false;
            } 
            if(pieces < reorder){
                window.alert("Re-order Level cannot be greater than pieces available!!");
                return false;
            }
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            $.ajax({
                url : "scripts/products.php", 
                data : { "category_key1" : category_key, "branch_code1" : branch_code, "product_name1" : product_name, "pieces1" : pieces, "measurement1" : measurement, "price1" : price, "reorder1" : reorder, "exp_date1" : exp_date, "note1" : note}, 
                dataType : "html",
                type : "post"
            }).done(function(data) {
                window.alert("Product successfully created!!!");
                $('#register_formProduct')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Unbind the click event or off the click events.
You have to include one latest version of jquery file ,not too many jquery.

```
$("#nav_page_a").unbind("").on("click", function () {
$("#load_here").load("link 1.php");
});
$("#nav_page_b").unbind("click").on("click", function () {
$("#load_here").load("link 2.php");
});
$("#nav_page_c").unbind("click").on("click", function () {
$("#load_here").load("link 3.php");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, i was able to come up with what finally works

```
$("#nav_page_i").unbind("click").on("click", function () {
$("#load_here").load("addproduct.php", function () {

$(".table").change(function(){
var val1 = +$("#pieces").val();
var val2 = +$("#reorder").val();

if(!(val1 > val2)){
$("#reorder").val((val1));
}
});

$("#submit_product").click(function() {
var category_key = $("#category_key").val();
var branch_code = $("#branch_code").val();
var product_name = $("#product_name").val();
var pieces = $("#pieces").val();
var measurement = $("#measurement").val();
var price = $("#price").val();
var reorder = $("#reorder").val();
var exp_date = $("#exp_date").val();
var note = $("#note").val();
if (exp_date == '' || reorder == '' || category_key == '' || pieces == '' || price == '' || branch_code == '' || measurement == '' || product_name == '') {
window.alert("Insertion Failed, Some Fields are Blank....!!");
} else {
if(pieces < reorder){
window.alert("Re-order Level cannot be greater than pieces available!!");
}else{
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("scripts/products.php", {
category_key1: category_key,
branch_code1: branch_code,
product_name1: product_name,
pieces1: pieces,
measurement1: measurement,
price1: price,
reorder1: reorder,
exp_date1: exp_date,
note1: note
}, function(data) {
window.alert("Product successfully created!!!");
$('#register_formProduct')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
});
}
}
});
});
});
```

This is my actual code from my work and it's working fine.